# fortify warning multiple definitions found for class root cause

Tags: warnings, fortify

I have same Java file name with different package when i scanning am getting below warning

> fortify warning multiple definitions found for class root cause

What issue going to cause by above warning?

Answer (score 0):

Well, this warning not gonna cause any issue.
But for sure this can be eliminated.
-exclude "class absolute path here" option can be used through the command line (much easier through UI) to eliminate those warnings.